Amplify Hosting compute logs / Cloudwatch log group does not exist
I am deploy Nextjs14 with NextAuth v5.
I have some problem with auth, but I cannot find log groups in Monitoring/Hosting compute logs tab.
When I go into CloudWatch, it says 'does not exist'.


The ServiceRole I used for deployment also has the necessary permissions.
        {
            "Sid": "AmplifySSRCreateLogGroup",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/amplify/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AmplifySSRPushLogs",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/amplify/*:log-stream:*"
        }


I'm not sure why, but after I changed the ServiceRole from a custom role to the default role created by Amplify, now I can see CloudWatch log group.
